# How can I include a field annotated with @StringDef in a Parcelable?

Tags: android, parcelable

I have a StringDef annotated interface

```
@StringDef({
    SpecialString.A,
    SpecialString.B
})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface SpecialString {
    String B = "BBB";
    String A = "AAA";
}
```

Which I use on a field in a parcelable object

```
public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {

    private final @SpecialString String mType;

    protected MyParcelable (Parcel in) {
        //Android studio shows an error for this line declaring 
        //"Must be one of SpecialString.A, SpecialString.B"
        mType = in.readString();
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(mType);
    }

}
```

How can I handle parceling a String annotated by `@StringDef` without resorting to suppressing with `//noinspection WrongConstant`?

Comment: You could not write the actual string to the `Parcel`. Instead, write something else (e.g., an `int`) that you use to decide which of the strings to use when reading in the `Parcel` (e.g., via a `switch` statement). Personally, I'd just live with the `noinspection`. There are limits on the sophistication of these sorts of Lint checks.

Comment: It was this same issue which lead me to realize that I wasn't benefitting from that much by choosing to use @StringDef as opposed to final static String. Is there any particular reason why you are choosing to use explicitly annotated strings?

Comment: It seemed like a good way to enforce only correct values being passed into the library project, without using an enum. I don't think a noinspection clause is too much of a cost, but I thought there would be a cleaner solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StringDef fields are supported by Parcelable but there is currently no way to ensure the value read back is one of the accepted values.

The method can be safely ignored in Android Studio by adding the comment `noinspection WrongConstant`

Safer alternatives may be to use an Enum and read it with `MyEnum.valueOf(readString)` or as CommonsWare suggested, to write an int ordinal or constant instead of the String and do a lookup when the value is read.